# Is it a good idea to use MQ to store data in DB?

Tags: scalability, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm going to use rabbitMQ as a message broker and switch most of the scripts to sending data to queue instead of performing direct writes/reads. Consumer will get those messages and perform corresponding operations. In my dreams this will give me more flexibility choosing DB engine, app level sharding and so on. But is it a good idea generally? Or am I missing something? Current write load is ~15k inserts/deletes for mysql and 30-50k sets for redis instances. Read load is the same ~15-20k selects, and 50-70k gets for redis.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue you'll face will be the fact that your DB writes will be asynchronously processed. If a client writes data to the DB and then instantly reads it back, the value might not be what it originally inserted because the Rabbit queue might have been very busy or slow, delaying the update operation. Or an admin might accidentally purge your queue and then you'll have all these clients thinking their transactions had been committed but nothing will have been stored.

This sounds like a classic case of premature optimization. It's a solution in search of a problem, and you should probably avoid doing it.

Comment: Yes, it's a premature optimization by definition. Async for DB is something that I want. I don't want users to wait for DB to finish writing. Instead I want to make sure all data is written to queue and then rely on HA-clustered-queues of rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

With amqp you can run a none asynchronous operations using a RPC way, with this kind of architecture you should figure out all problems related with asynchronous operations.

Comment: Architecture of current system is already more or less event-driven. Some parts are written in python twisted, some in node.js, so it's not a revolutionary change.